# How to use jQuery without module

Tags: jquery, webpack

I'm using **Webpack + Gulp** to develop websites.

I use Webpack to bundle all JavaScript in Frontend and I do it well.

But backend used to use `<script src="jquery.js">` to use jQuery library.

Without using `<script src="jquery.js">`, backend can't use 'jQuery' or '$' from bundled javascript.

## For example.

### ./dev/index.html

```
...
script(src='js/app.js') // bundled file, jQuery's inside
script(src='js/backend.js')
```

### ./dev/js/app.js'

```
$('body').css('color', '#FFF');
```

### ./dev/js/backend.js'

```
$('body').css('color', '#000');
```

### webpack.config

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: 'js/app',
  },
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/build`,
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel',
      },
    ],
  },
  stats: {
    children: false,
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'dev'),
      '../node_modules',
      '../plugins',
      '../global_utils',
    ],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    extensions: ['', '.js'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
      'root.jQuery': 'jquery',
    }),
  ],
};
```

app.js works perfectly.

But an error '$ is not defined.' occurs in executing backend.js.

Is there any way let backend.js can use '$'?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see where you are providing entry point to build backend.js?

Comment: Webpack runs only in Frontend. Backend just add <script src='path/to/their_scripts.js'> in html and coding in their_scripts.js without webpack.

Comment: If jquery is not bundled with the backend.js, how will it be able to make use of the library? You can also create a separate webpack config to bundle the backendjs however you need.